# How could I troubleshoot my minecraft connection to servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently I've tried joining a friend's minecraft server, although it worked fine for the first few days, I suddenly stopped being able to connect properly, it lets me into the server but around 20 seconds later I get kicked with the reason `java.io.IOException: Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. This is constant and doesn't seem to be affected by player presence, a VPN/no VPN, a whole different client, a clean Minecraft re-install, nothing has worked in fixing it, it working every few hundred attempts seems completely random.

This is not the first time I've had an issue with connecting to a small server, I've had some friends create servers in the past and it happened on one of them, however not on the others.

Variables I've collected:

- It has occured when:

  - Server is using Waterfall, Paper or Spigot.
  - Server is hosted in different regions.
  - I have attempted all of the above fixes.
  - First joining the server.
  - Being on the server for a few days.
  - **Using Essentials.** (This is my best guess as to the cause, I feel like it wasn't happening before Essentials was added to the current server)
- It hasn't occured locally.

Pinging the server in a cmd works and it pings and replies with no losses (Tried up to `-n 150`).

The only weird thing about my connection is that I am relying on a TP-Link adapter to bring WiFi to my room and an Ethernet cable connected to it and my computer.

Answer (score -1):

If your friends Minecraft server is run with low ram then it will not be able to handle many people but if your error says you got kicked by your remote host then your remote host must be your computer so if your getting kicked by your own computer it might be data usage or high ping. I'm not an expert.